# Free web site load/performance testing on Windows

Tags: performance

Can anyone suggest a decent free performance/load testing tool that runs on Windows. I checked some up, but most are linux based. Though I could run a virtual linux box, I'd rather stick to a pure Windows system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [openSTA](http://opensta.org/).

Comment: Aseeem, it looks fine at first glance, but the last version I could find is from 2007 and there is mention of installing on NT server and Windows 2000. Does this work on more recent servers too?

Comment: No idea if its compatible with Win 2k. Should work on XP+ OS'es.

Comment: Ok, looking at the online documenation here http://opensta.org/docs/ug/os-getti.htm#23717, it works on Win 2k and NT 4.0 with SP5.

Answer (score 0):

Please check CloudTest Lite - cloud based free tool for performance testing web apps [soasta here](http://www.soasta.com/info-center/press-releases/cloudtest-lite-edition-announcement)